# Continue div's content in another div if filled

Tags: jquery, split, divide

I need your help. I have content contained in a div. This must have 300px height,
but the content is longer than the height, so I need the content to continue in the next div with the same 300px of height.

This needs to be like a printing module that is split into these divs in order to print them separately. I will appreciate any kind of help!

What I need is something like this:

```
<!--Turn this: -->

    <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

    /******Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation****/ 
    </div>

    <div class="content"></div>



   <!--Into this: -->
    <div class="content">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

    (supose this text fills the div)

    </div>

    <div class="content">
    (and the content continues here)
    /******Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation****/ </div>
```

Comment: Did you solved your problem??:)

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a P tag and add content inside this tag (Height of the tag and height of the div will be different if it exceed the content.
2. Get the height of the first div (fixed height) and First P tag inside first DIV(height based on content)
3. while height of

   is less than the height of the p.(height of DIV is less that height of P, Means exceeds the content.)
     3.1 Pop some content from the P tag(first P inside First DIV) and add to a variable var_exceed_content.
4. Move all the var_exceed_content variable value to second div(continue DIV).:)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="content" style='  height:20px;
    background:blue;
    margin-bottom:10px;'>
    <p>    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna aliquam erat volutpat.

    /******Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerci tation****/.</p>
</div>
<div class="content_continues" style='    
    background: green;
    margin-bottom:10px;
    padding:10px;'>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript code:**

```
var cont1 = $('.content');
var cont1Height = cont1.height();

var p1 = $('.content p');
var p1Height = p1.height();


var p2 = $('.content_continues p');

//get text and explode it as an array
var p1text = p1.text();
p1text = p1text.split('');

//prepare p2 text
p2text = [];

//if greater height
while (p1Height > cont1Height) {

    //remove last character
    lastChar = p1text.pop();

    //prepend to p2 text
    p2text.unshift(lastChar);

    //reassemble p1 text
    p1temp = p1text.join('');

    //place back to p1
    p1.text(p1temp);

    //re-evaluate height
    p1Height = p1.height();

    //loop
}

//if less than, assemble p2 text and render to p2 container
p2.text(p2text.join(''));
```

Please check this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/P7Dfz/81/)

Comment: ty all guys, i took the Fasil kk´s code and it seems to work but now i got a problem. The content has a list so i changed .text() to .html() in order to get the list tag but i got this on the second div!


  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ytPNu.png

appreciate you help!!!

Answer (score 0):

you could write a some javascript to get the overflow and append it to the next content div.

```
if (contentdiv.length > x ) {
    nextdiv.innerHTML = contentdiv.innerHTML.substring(x);
}
```

yeah...that's dirty. i think that's how you use the substring meth; it's been a while. you'd have to figure out a good way to get the 'x' value though.

Comment: ty all guys, i took the Fasil kk´s code and it seems to work but now i got a problem. The content has a list so i changed .text() to .html() in order to get the list tag but i got this on the second div!


  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ytPNu.png

appreciate you help!!!